# Change printed text color in Idle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

Is there a way to specify the color a text is printed within Idle for Python 3.2?

I'm looking for something like:

```
print("foo", "#fafafa")
print("bar", "#4f4f4f")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html#syntax-colors

> To change the color scheme, edit the [Colors] section in config.txt.

Edit: As you've edited your question, here is an edited answer. See

http://www.daimi.au.dk/~mailund/scripting2005/lecture-notes/process-management.html

for how to use terminal escape sequences in Python to change the color of things.

Will they work in IDLE? I don't know. But they will work in most terminals.

Comment: I think the question is how to do it dynamically from a running program.

Comment: Oh I hate it when that happens!

Comment: Well, ANSI escapes are definitely not recognized by IDLE. Anyone know how to call the Colorizer on something I output myself?