# Changing individual line colours in idle python

Tags: python, colors, python-idle

I am trying to find a way to make separate lines different colors like this (This was done on word):[image: Example image]

I know there are ways doing this with OS but that changes the color for every line of text, not just a separate line.

Also I cant add any plugins so it needs to be done using vanilla commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change printed text color in Idle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795330/change-printed-text-color-in-idle)

Comment: No, just tried, did not work

Comment: It's not because the answer does not work, that the question is not a duplicate... You ask exactly the same. Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108559/how-to-print-colour-color-in-python), so maybe try this one then

Comment: Look at the answer which is aimed specificly for idle